# Restore collection values in a edited input text

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I have several text input that show the value in a collection, as:

```
<input type="text" id="myval" value={{myvalue}}>
```

I would like to have a `Reset` button that restore the original collection value, after the input text has benn edited. I tried with:

```
Router.render('mypage')
```

but it does not work.
 I would like to solve this without adding a template helper for each input value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render a template , that should be user [Blaze.toHTML](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_tohtml) or [Blaze.toHTMLWithData](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/blaze_getdata)

For your case, you can use following code to re-render again:

```
$('#urformdiv').html(Blaze.toHTML(Template.mypage));
```

Comment: It works (see [example](http://meteorpad.com/pad/bscwJmetdm9LLY8fS/MyInput)). Unfortunately using iron-router, it loose the router data (and the `{{>yield}}` template render in a weird mode).

Answer (score 0):

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338091/how-do-i-reload-the-current-ironrouter-route) the solution to restore the data using iron-router:

```
Router.current().render(Template.mypage).data();
```